# Scan non default outlook inbox for email?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am using the following vba code which checks for any emails with a specific subject heading.

The problem is it checks my default outlook inbox folder when I need it to check the inbox of my other email account NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk

Can someone please show me how I would do this? Thanks in advance

```
Sub Macro1() Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
     Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
     Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
     Dim I As Long
     Dim olMail As Variant


     Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
     Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     Set myTasks = Fldr.Items


  Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""New Supplier Request: Ticket""")
  If Not (olMail Is Nothing) Then



    For Each myItem In myTasks
        If myItem.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each myAttachment In myItem.Attachments
            If InStr(myAttachment.DisplayName, ".txt") Then
                I = I + 1
                myAttachment.SaveAsFile "\\uksh000-file06\Purchasing\NS\Unactioned\" & myAttachment
                End If
            Next
        End If

    Next



For Each myItem In myTasks
myItem.Delete
Next

Call Macro2

Else
MsgBox "There Are No New Supplier Requests."
End If
End Sub
```

outlook folder structure:

```
account1@hewden.co.uk
Inbox
Drafts
Sent

NewSuppliers@hewden.co.uk
Inbox
Drafts
Sent
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain what i mean by 'same level' ... Also ... what version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: Is that an Exchange mailbox? Is it already open in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following, assuming that the folder you want is at the same level in the folder hierarchy

```
Set Items = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders("YouFolderName").Items
```

See here for more details ... http://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/

---

Have you tried the following function from the above link ...

```
Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim FoldersArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
    FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
End If
'Convert folderpath to array
FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.item(FoldersArray(0))
If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
        Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
        Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
        Set oFolder = SubFolders.item(FoldersArray(i))
        If oFolder Is Nothing Then
            Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
        End If
    Next
End If
'Return the oFolder
Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
Exit Function

GetFolderPath_Error:
Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
Exit Function
End Function
```

You may need to use the technique here first to find out the actual folder name ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607.aspx

---

In the image below, the Drafts, Clients, Outbox folders are all on the same level (they share the same parent folder james@...com), but the ChildFolder folder is not (it's parent is Drafts).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't appear to be working, it says an object could not be found

Comment: Can you post an image of your folder structure? Also, that link deals with other cases where the folder is at a different level :0)

Comment: please see updated question with outlook folder structure

Comment: Are `account1@hewden.co.uk` and `NewSuppliers@hewden.co.uk` on the same level?

Comment: what do you mean by same level?

Comment: Where is that folder is located relative to the top and/or Inbox folder?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I think I understand what you mean, however newsuppliers@hewden.co.uk is a completely different account/mailbox

Comment: Try `olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder("NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk")`

Comment: @0m3r I am trying to do something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526145/excel-vba-create-meeting-in-non-default-calendar

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just specify the name of your 2nd mailbox as a Folder.

```
Set Fldr = olNs.Folders("My 2nd mailbox").Folders("Sub Folder")
```

If you want the main inbox of the 2nd account, then you specify this as the sub folder of the account.

```
Set Fldr = olNs.Folders("My 2nd Inbox").Folders("Inbox")
```

Note that it's the name of the mailbox you use, not the e-mail address. Let me know how you get on.