# Excel VBA create Meeting in Non-Default Calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How do I create a Meeting on the non default calendar of the non default email address in outlook using VBA code?

The code that I have creates the invites in the default calendar of the default email address:

```
Sub CreateAppointmentOutlook()

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim oRecip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Set oApp = New Outlook.Application

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set oApt = oApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    oApt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    Debug.Print (ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    With oApt
        .Subject = "Test"
        ' do some other stuff
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

The closest I could come to even attempting to change calendar was this [reference](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/working-vba-nondefault-outlook-folders/). To even begin to try to implement this code in my example I did the below as a test

```
Sub Whatever()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace

Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim Items As Object
Set Items = GetFolderPath("otheremail@contoso.com\Calendar").Items
Debug.Print (Items.Parent.FolderPath)
Debug.Print ("End")
End Sub
```

But I get a Run-time error '91' : Object variable or With block variable not set on line Set Items = GetFolderPath("otheremail@contoso.com\Calendar").Items

**UPDATE**

This code runs:

```
Sub Whatever()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 
Dim oApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder

Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = ns.Folders("otheremail@contoso.com")

Dim CalItems As Outlook.Items
Set CalItems = oFolder.Items

End Sub
```

But how then to create a calendar entry on this other CalItems folder collection?

Comment: When you `Dim as Object`, you need to use 'CreateObject("Library.Member")'. Plus, if you use `items`, that is a Collection, not an Object. Please reference [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation).

Comment: @JVBA thanks - but I need a little more explanation on how to declare "Items" then. I get the late vs early binding. Dim Items As Collection ?

Comment: I would say since each `MAPI` represents each email account in your Client (Outlook, for example), you could, `Dim fld as Outlook.Folder`. Then, `Set fld = ns.Folders("otheremail@here.com\Calendar")`. Then say, `Dim CalItems As Outlook.Items` & `Set CalItems = fld.Items`

Answer (score 0):

This code will create a Appointment on non default calendar in a non default account in Outlook. Hope this helps someone else out in future:

```
Sub Whatever()
Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim oApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set recip = ns.CreateRecipient("otheremail@contoso.com")

If recip.Resolve Then
    Set otherFolder = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, olFolderCalendar)
End If

Set oApt = otherFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

oApt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    With oApt
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Start = "15/04/2019 09:00"
        .End = "15/04/2019 09:10"
        .Location = "The Business Meeting Room"
        .Recipients.Add ("user@contoso.com")
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to check if `otherFolder` is nothing or not before trying to set `oApt` too. You will get an error if the `recip` doesn't resolve.